# DATEDIF FUNCTION not functioning as expected

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

What's the reason this array formula (in cell H1) is not producing the indented result of showing the age range of each person at the time of "First Call"?

```
={"Array";arrayformula(IF(DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") < 25, "18-24",
IF(AND((DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") >= 25), (DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") < 35)), "25-34",
IF(AND(DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") >= 35, DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") < 45), "35-44",
IF(AND(DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") >= 45, DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") < 55), "45-54", "55+")))))}
```

[image]

I tested the formula outside of an array (in column G) to check for errors and it worked as expected

```
=IF(DATEDIF(F2, C2, "Y") < 25, "18-24",
IF(AND((DATEDIF(F2, C2, "Y") >= 25), (DATEDIF(F2, C2, "Y") < 35)), "25-34",
IF(AND(DATEDIF(F2, C2, "Y") >= 35, DATEDIF(F2, C2, "Y") < 45), "35-44",
IF(AND(DATEDIF(F2, C2, "Y") >= 45, DATEDIF(F2, C2, "Y") < 55), "45-54", "55+"))))
```

[image]

Comment: You need to decide if you are using Excel or Google sheets - you should know which as many functions behave differently. Then we may be able to check the behavior.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for highlighting. I'm using Goole Sheets but that wasn't clear in the post. I've updated the title accordingly. Is it poor form of me to include the 'excel-formula' tag?

Comment: @Mikey you make the distinction in the tags not the title.  Yes, it is considered bad form to use Excel in your tags when you want a google sheets answer.  There are many formula that are not transferable between the two and can waste yours and other's time by giving answers that will not work for your situation.  I have edited to remove the Excel tag and fixed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Arrayformula in sheets use * instead of AND

```
={"Array";arrayformula(IF(DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") < 25, "18-24",
IF((DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") >= 25) * (DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") < 35), "25-34",
IF((DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") >= 35) * (DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") < 45),  "35-44",
IF((DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") >= 45) * (DATEDIF(F2:F, C2:C, "Y") < 55),  "45-54", "55+")))))}
```